# Facing 409 issue in Test Rail

Tags: testrail

I am facing an issue :

> [ERROR] Tests run: 987, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 940, Time
>   elapsed: 3,856.585 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite [ERROR]
>   afterTestMethod(com.framework.c4.testcases.PRFileDropTest)  Time
>   elapsed: 72.695 s  <<< FAILURE! com.framework.testrail.APIException:
>   TestRail API return HTTP 409 (No additional error message received)
>     at
>   com.framework.c4.testcases.PRFileDropTest.afterTestMethod(PRFileDropTest.java:85)

How can i resolve this could you please help me on this??

Comment: Could you please give us some background and code?

Comment: please provide some example code, in which language, test framework and so on...

Comment: Its implemented in Java, When we are trying to write(post to testrail API) Then it throwing an 409 error

Answer (score 0):

TestRail instances are backed up once a day normally between 02:00 UTC and 05:00 UTC. The elapsed time of the backup depends on the size of the database. In the event of an HTTP 409 response, you should just retry the request in a few minutes e.g.

If you need further support, please contact Gurock directly

Think that you need to put up a support ticket as all the links point to the same problem.

https://discuss.gurock.com/t/this-testrail-instance-is-currently-in-maintenance-mode/10278
https://discuss.gurock.com/t/api-use-and-maintenance/10398
https://discuss.gurock.com/t/409-maintennace-error-is-always-thrown/12942